# Pascal's Law related

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, free-body-diagram

Which is more valid for The pressure intensity at a point in a fluid is the same in all directions, only when:

- The fluid has zero viscosity and is at rest? or
- There is no motion of one fluid layer relative to an adjacent layer?

Please provide an explanation.

Comment: This reads a bit like a homework question? Also, I don't know what pressure intensity is.

Comment: Not a homework question, our professor answered the first statement "The fluid has zero viscosity and is at rest" but the internet says "There is no motion of one fluid layer relative to an adjacent layer"but there is no explanation given.

Comment: I also don't know what you mean with "more valid". It's either valid, or it is not.

Comment: I acknowledge your confusion and I will try to rephrase my question....I just want to know if both choices are correct to satisfy the statement "the pressure intensity at a point in a fluid is the same in all directions".Also,  they are quite similar to other question I posted but I just want to the reason behind it... Thank you.