# Normal Stress in Fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain

When will the normal stress be the same in all directions at a point in a fluid? Is it when the fluid has zero viscosity and is at rest or one fluid layer has no motion relative to an adjacent layer? Please give an explanation.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/552690/

Comment: It is when the rate of deformation tensor is diagonal, and all elements on the diagonal are equal.  In other words, the rate of deformation tensor is a scalar times the identity (metric) tensor.